# Compare closed type with open type

Tags: c#, reflection, generics

I'm curious how to check if given type is closed *version* of open type. For instance

```
public bool IsGenericList(Type source)
{
    return (source.IsGenericType &&
            /*here goes the manipulation on source type*/ == typeof(List<>));
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition.aspx):

```
public bool IsGenericList(Type source)
{
    return source.IsGenericType &&
           source.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(List<>);
}
```

Comment: This is what I had tried at the first place but thought it doesn't work because I had bug somewhere else in code. Thanks anyway :)